# Regex - Matching groups in URL parameters

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, regex-group

I need to extract values from this string:

```
urlTest?paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB
```

So, I thought something like this:

```
urlTest?paramA=(.*)&paramB=(.*)
```

But, in some cases I don't have the paramB, or, in some cases I have '&' and '=' inside the params values.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should not have `&` or `=` inside the param values. A properly encoded url would use `%26` and `%3D`

Comment: What programming language are you working with? Most would have a native ability to parse a URL query string.

Comment: It's not a common URL, so,  unfortunately, I can't use escape chars (%26 and %3D).

I'm programming for iOS (Objective-C), but if someone help me with a regex in other language, I'll be happy anyway =). 


I'm using this to interact with some screens. A crazy project hahaha
It's like a command: `doSomething?withThis=aaa&andThis=bbb`

Comment: Traditionally, one would split the string on & first, then split each sub-string on =, but if you have & and = in your values, that's tricky.  Can you post some examples of the strings you'd need to parse please?

Comment: Unfortunately, the design of this application is not mine. The things are a 'little' messy.

Escaping the content values and performing a `for` matching each pair, or spliting string using `&` and `=`  solve the problem.
But, in my cenario I don't have this possibility. It's outside my control. I'm fixing a legacy code.

Example:

`commandRun?withAtributes=valueA&withAltAtributes=valueB`   

valueA can be a value like:

`commandStop?stopTime=321&delay=321`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Chop off the question mark and everything before
$str = preg_replace('~^[^?]*+\?~', '', $str);
$groups = parse_str($str);
```

http://php.net/parse_str

Comment: Where's the PHP tag on this question?

Comment: Added iOS + objective-c tags. I'm targeting the expression itself, but to avoid problems, I changed to avoid conflicts. I apologize.

Comment: @Geert, I tested your regex and it extracts the first part as you said.

But I need the separeted values using regex grouping. I need a regex with all requirements to give me values (group a = valuea / group b = valueb).

Thanks

Comment: @DaniloGomes: right, my regex only cleans up the string for use with PHP’s `parse_str` function. It is that function that does the magic.